# "Edit with IDLE" is not working for .py files inside importlib package. during debugging, I cant go to source line, only for importlib package

Tags: python3, idle

This is the default python package named 'importlib', I am trying to access and open/edit .py files inside this package.

Comment: is this windows 11? Windows 11 'hides' the open with options

Comment: it is windows 10, this is the directory    C:\Program Files\Python310\Lib\importlib  where I cant edit the python files.

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: it is not any code error, i want to edit the python files. but whenever i right click, everything disappear. that is the first problem i am facing. second problem is whenever I want to debug the code related to this package, i cant navigat through the source lines though IDLE debugger is showing the line and line numbers only inside debugger.